# why urlConnection.getContentType() is giving null for some images reading from an url?

Tags: java, urlconnection

I am working on Java 7 and tried to read mime type from an URL by below code. In maximum scenario urlConnection.getContentType() gives content type but in some specific scenario it gives null.

For example, in the below code, I am able to read mime type for url2 but url1 is giving null.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

class readMimeType{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url1 = "https://akumyndigitalcontent.blob.core.windows.net/visitattachments/1804915_0_2_87_.jpeg";
        String url2 = "https://gigwalk-multitenant-api-server.s3.amazonaws.com/public_uploads/62ae090584074fefeeada538c5ceb206fedf58f9e9a2aef463908fb53793bd64a28ed152427f96eb923cb789e947a6984db1c3460fcf373fb589b9e3051f6ef8/9a71308d-3da2-4e96-88b9-cc75a7470db3";

        try {
            URL serverUrl = new URL(url1);
            URLConnection urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection();
            HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;
            httpConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            InputStream initialStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

            String mimeType = urlConnection.getContentType();

            System.out.println("mimeType::::" + mimeType);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he just doesn't know the content type

Comment: I used F12 to check, and found that this link doesn't have context type.

Comment: what can be the solution because I am using this in my project where I have to save the content type in JSON ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the URLConnection#getContentType [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType--), it says

> Returns the value of the content-type header field.

So if the header value is missing the `content-type` header, the method will return null.

Use `curl` to check:

```
curl -I https://akumyndigitalcontent.blob.core.windows.net/visitattachments/1804915_0_2_87_.jpeg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31622400
Content-Length: 2794649
Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Jun 2019 00:25:00 GMT
ETag: 0x8D6E6F0BFBA22BC
Vary: Origin
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: f5962c19-901e-0083-78f8-20a0ca000000
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 08:24:58 GMT
```

```
curl -I https://gigwalk-multitenant-api-server.s3.amazonaws.com/public_uploads/62ae090584074fefeeada538c5ceb206fedf58f9e9a2aef463908fb53793bd64a28ed152427f96eb923cb789e947a6984db1c3460fcf373fb589b9e3051f6ef8/9a71308d-3da2-4e96-88b9-cc75a7470db3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: LXyjyXfMWNmwYfkUhiGnbyJBE4WovVwUTNi7ELXmDYpLtwGHVl1BfBPYgxgDazK44sIIwXFMv+4=
x-amz-request-id: FF7CE75150E28EB3
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 08:25:15 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Oct 2018 02:15:15 GMT
ETag: "15ad210d28be6a37af2c0e37a5c30e6b"
x-amz-storage-class: STANDARD_IA
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 200785
Server: AmazonS3
```

As you can see, only one of them has the `content-type` field in the response headers.

An alternative way is to download the file and check. See: https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-mime-type

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation

Returns:
the content type of the resource that the URL references, or null if not known.

If the server does not return the Content-Type header the getContentType() method cannot know the type.

Answer (score 0):

```
URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(fileName)
```

was returning **null** to me, because the **fileName** contained " " - space character.
Fixed it by:

```
URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(fileName.substringAfterLast(" "))
```

*This may not be exactly your problem, but i decided to leave it here for others searching for similar issue.*